# How do I read and write the inputs from a file in c++ specified format?

Tags: c++

I have this basic algorithm that checks if the the number correspond to his position in the array (there's always just 1 case that corresponds):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, winner, n_test = 1;
    cin >> n;
    while(n != 0){
        int *arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            std::cin>>arr[i];
            if ((i+1) == arr[i]){
                winner = arr[i];
            }
        }
        delete[] arr;

        cout << "Test " << n_test << endl;
        cout << winner << endl;
            
        n_test += 1;
        cin >> n;
    }
}
```

Example input:

```
4
2 4 3 1
```

The output must be 3.

This algorithm works just fine, but I need to take the inputs from a `.in` file. The `.in` file looks like this:

```
20
1 6 10 2 13 4 5 17 12 18 3 14 7 15 9 11 19 20 8 16
20
15 5 4 13 1 10 18 16 2 19 12 11 3 9 8 14 7 17 6 20
20
6 9 18 20 14 11 13 17 2 10 12 1 7 4 3 19 8 15 16 5
0
```

The program stops when `n = 0`.

Then I need to write the outputs in a file that looks like this:

```
Test 1
1

Test 2
20

Test 3
10
```

Comment: An easy way is using redirects in your shell like `./a.out < input.in > result.out`

Comment: If you want to learn to read a file with C++, try a simpler exercise first. And searching for "C++ read file" will give you many examples of the method.

Comment: https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/basic_istream/
, same for ostream to write

... including code examples

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `fstream` library. You can include it with `#include <fstream>`.

To read it, you can create a variable that has the inputs from your file and then use a `while` loop and the function `getline()` to add every line from your file into a string.

To write in the file, you can use the operator `<<` to insert a string into the file.

If you want to go more in details and to see an example, you can check the following website: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_files.asp